yq wont recognize single quotation marks around the field when trying to split large YAML file into smaller ones
I have a large YAML file containing info about video games.
---
-
    Name: Metal Gear Solid HD Collection
    Console: PS3
    Genre: Stealth 
    Progression: Unplayed
    Maintenance: Perfect!
-
    Name: Metal Gear Solid 4 Guns of the Patriots
    Console: PS3
    Genre: Stealth 
    Progression: Unplayed
    Maintenance: Perfect!
-
    Name: Metal Gear Rising Revengeance
    Console: PS3
    Genre: Power Fantasy
    Progression: Compleat (Blade Wold DLC to play)
    Maintenance: Perfect!
-

I am trying to split the large file into a file per game. I found a great solution to this with using:
yq e GameCollection.yaml -s .Name

But this gives the following error
Error: cannot index array with 'Name' (strconv.ParseInt: parsing "Name": invalid syntax)

I'm assuming that this is because it is trying to treat Name as a string so I wrap it in single quotes to make it more like a String. I found this solution here, (in the comments under the most upvoted answer), which allowed me to see a different error message and move past this issue.
yq e GameCollection.yaml -s '.Name'

This gives me a different Error and I think it's because Name is not a unique identifier as there are sometimes the same game on multiple consoles (such as Skyrim)
Error: bad split document expression: 1:1: invalid input text "'.Name'"

I found, what I thought was a great solution to this, by adding an index so that duplicate names can just increment! I found that solution here.
yq e GameCollection.yaml -s '.Name + "_" + $index'

But it gives me a similar error.
Error: bad split document expression: 1:1: invalid input text "'.Name"

I tried again a few times as I think I just don't understand the syntax.
yq e GameCollection.yaml -s '.Name' + "_" + '$index'
Error: bad split document expression: 1:1: invalid input text "'.Name'"

yq e GameCollection.yaml -s '.Name' + "_" + $index
Error: bad split document expression: 1:1: invalid input text "'.Name'"

yq e GameCollection.yaml -s .Name + "_" + '$index'
Error: cannot index array with 'Name' (strconv.ParseInt: parsing "Name": invalid syntax)

It's almost like it doesn't like the single quotes.
What can I try to fix it?

The problem has nothing to do with the use of quotation marks. The cause is much simpler: your file contains documents that are single-element arrays. So there is no .Name at the top level, but it's a key to the first element of each array. Therefore, you need to specify it like this:
yq e .[] GameCollection.yaml -s .Name

Some background info
Compare your file with the one from the other question you looked at.
The one from the other question:
---
name: first
metadata: a

Your file:
---
-
    Name: Metal Gear Solid HD Collection

Notice the extra - line: it's significant.
Another way to debug the issue is to convert your file into JSON format, which some people find clearer and helps to show structure more explicitly:
yq -o json GameCollection.yaml

Note all the [ ... ] showing that these are arrays.

With .[0].Name you're just dumping the whole input into a single file which gets the name of the first item's .Name, i.e. Metal Gear Solid HD Collection.yml. To instead get three files, namely Metal Gear Solid HD Collection.yml, Metal Gear Solid 4 Guns of the Patriots.yml, and Metal Gear Rising Revengeance.yml with their respective items as contents, first destructure the array using .[] before splitting to just .Name, i.e. yq e ".[]" GameCollection.yaml -s .Name

Okay I think I understand this a bit better now I ran your command yq e GameCollection.yaml -s .[0].Name and this creates a new file where the name of the file is the first game in the array and the content is the same as the previous one but the 3 dashes at the thop are removed.
I edited the file to not have 3 dashes at the top and then used find and replace to replace the single dash with 3 more dashes. removing the indent too. Using the Json command you send I can see it is just a bunch of objects in the file and no longer an array.
But I am still unable to split it, any ideas why?

PMF beat me to it as I was typing out the reply! and came up with a solution, thank you so much!
